# Баг: изменяется размер формы при сворачивании

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пишу софтину. Совтина имеет главную форму. Если эту форму свертуть, то сбивается размеры колонок в `DataGridView` и `SplitterDistance` во всех `SplitContainer`:

**До сворачивания:**

[image]

**После сворачивания:**

[image]

Comment: А как вы обрабатываете изменение размеров окна?

Comment: Через событие `Resize`, Код: http://yadi.sk/d/0ijrpFvzA3mfv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте анализировать в обработчике события `Resize`, не минимизировано ли ваше окно:

```
private void TranslatorFormResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        return; // ничего не надо делать, окно минимизировано
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все теперь работает как надо.

Comment: @Janycz: Пожалуйста!